# tinymce saving issue - PHP

Tags: php, ajax, forms, asynchronous, tinymce

VIDEO OF PROBLEM: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6RZHMQueDc&feature=youtu.be

When i press submit form button, I call onsubmit method that sends the data off with ajax (async false).

On return of the ajax call, it echos back the content of the tinymce textarea. If I press save once, nothing is returned (but the call is successful and returns my test echo), I I press save a second time, then the tinymce textarea has something in it for the ajax to return.

Is there a setting I have missed out somewhere, where the textarea must be updated on every key stroke or something like that? Or where on save, the textarea is synchronously pushed into the textarea and then allows the save to do its job rather than asynchronously?

Any ideas?

Here are the settings I currently use:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "jbimages,autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist",
        language : "en",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,|,jbimages",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : false,

        // This is required for the image paths to display properly
        relative_urls : false,

        // Style formats (OPTIONAL)
        style_formats : [
            {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
            {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
            {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
            {title : 'Table styles'},
            {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
        ]

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before submit call tinyMCE.triggerSave();

Comment: That's the one. How on earth did I miss that hahaha! Good man!.. That was rhetorical btw.. It's coz i'm a noob. I already know the answer ^_^